# Merge json into another json as subdocument

Tags: javascript, json

I want to merge two json files in a way that matching `stop_id` in second json is nested as a subdocument in first json.

This is what I mean:

**first.json**: This is a json file containing station stops for a train, for instance. Each has a `stop_id` field.

```
[
  {
    "stop_id":70021,
    "stop_name":"CALTRAIN - 22ND ST STATION",
    "stop_lat":37.757692,
    "stop_lon":-122.392318,
    "zone_id":3329
  },
  {
    "stop_id":70022,
    "stop_name":"CALTRAIN - 22ND ST STATION",
    "stop_lat":37.757692,
    "stop_lon":-122.392318,
    "zone_id":3329
  },
  {
    "stop_id":70151,
    "stop_name":"CALTRAIN - ATHERTON STATION",
    "stop_lat":37.464458,
    "stop_lon":-122.198152,
    "zone_id":3331
  }]
```

**second.json**: This contains a trip information related to a station, via the `stop_id`

```
[
  {
    "trip_id":"RTD8997283",
    "arrival_time":"05:40:00",
    "departure_time":"05:40:00",
    "stop_id":70021,
    "stop_sequence":1
  },
  {
    "trip_id":"RTD8997283",
    "arrival_time":"05:52:00",
    "departure_time":"05:52:00",
    "stop_id":70021,
    "stop_sequence":2
  },
  {
    "trip_id":"RTD8449096",
    "arrival_time":"07:33:00",
    "departure_time":"07:33:00",
    "stop_id":70022,
    "stop_sequence":1
  }]
```

I want to merge these document in a way that, matching `stop_id`s in second.json are nested below a `stop_id` document in first.json. So, for example, an end results of the merge would look like this:

**merged.json**

```
[{
    "stop_id": 70021,
    "stop_name": "CALTRAIN - 22ND ST STATION",
    "stop_lat": 37.757692,
    "stop_lon": -122.392318,
    "zone_id": 3329,
    "trip": [{
        "trip_id": "RTD8997283",
        "arrival_time": "05:40:00",
        "departure_time": "05:40:00",
        "stop_id": 70021,
        "stop_sequence": 1
    }, {
        "trip_id": "RTD8997283",
        "arrival_time": "05:52:00",
        "departure_time": "05:52:00",
        "stop_id": 70021,
        "stop_sequence": 2
    }]
}, {
    "stop_id": 70022,
    "stop_name": "CALTRAIN - 22ND ST STATION",
    "stop_lat": 37.757692,
    "stop_lon": -122.392318,
    "zone_id": 3329,
    "trip": [{
        "trip_id": "RTD8449096",
        "arrival_time": "07:33:00",
        "departure_time": "07:33:00",
        "stop_id": 70022,
        "stop_sequence": 1
    }]
}, {
    "stop_id": 70151,
    "stop_name": "CALTRAIN - ATHERTON STATION",
    "stop_lat": 37.464458,
    "stop_lon": -122.198152,
    "zone_id": 3331
}]
```

Any way to do such merges via javascript or any other approach, for large datasets?

Comment: If the dataset is large,  you may want to first convert your array of objects to a map (stopid -> object) for quicker lookup. Similarly for trips

Comment: Are you working on the server or the client?

Comment: Do you specifically want to do this in javascript, or would something like the `jq` command line tool be fine for your purposes?

Comment: @Yoda None. I'll simply import the data into an indexeddb then process everything within the browser. Handling the conversion will be a one time thing, and I'll do on my local pc, then will import the merged json for use

Comment: @KenB Edited the question. It can be done with whatever, it doesn't matter to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `array.forEach`.

```
first.forEach(function (val, index, theArray) {
   val.trip = [];
   second.forEach(function (val2, index, theArray) {
       if(val2.stop_id === val.stop_id){
           val.trip.push(val2);
       }
   });    
});

console.log(first);
```

A fiddle to play around. 
https://jsfiddle.net/u3etdqrz/3/

Comment: why the `.slice()`? You're already editing in place, why bother duplicating the array in memory?

Comment: @KenB: agree you are right, may be i am not sure on what context he is working... just to be on safer side...

Comment: `slice()` only shallow-copies the array itself, not its contents; you're still acting on the same objects internally, which you seem to understand since you're `console.log()`ing the original array at the end

Comment: Will give a try. Thanks for quick response

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```js
var stnList = [{"stop_id": 70021,"stop_name": "CALTRAIN - 22ND ST STATION",  "stop_lat": 37.757692,"stop_lon": -122.392318,"zone_id": 3329}, {  "stop_id": 70022,  "stop_name": "CALTRAIN - 22ND ST STATION",  "stop_lat": 37.757692,  "stop_lon": -122.392318,  "zone_id": 3329}, {  "stop_id": 70151,  "stop_name": "CALTRAIN - ATHERTON STATION",  "stop_lat": 37.464458,  "stop_lon": -122.198152,  "zone_id": 3331}];

var travelList = [{  "trip_id": "RTD8997283",  "arrival_time": "05:40:00",  "departure_time": "05:40:00",  "stop_id": 70021,  "stop_sequence": 1}, {  "trip_id": "RTD8997283",  "arrival_time": "05:52:00",  "departure_time": "05:52:00",  "stop_id": 70021,  "stop_sequence": 2}, {  "trip_id": "RTD8449096",  "arrival_time": "07:33:00",  "departure_time": "07:33:00",  "stop_id": 70022,  "stop_sequence": 1}]

travelList.forEach(function(t) {
  // Find oobject
  var _stn = stnList.find(function(stn) {
    return stn.stop_id === t.stop_id
  });
  
  // check if trip property is defined or not
  if (!_stn.trip) _stn.trip = [];
  _stn.trip.push(t);
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(stnList, 0, 4) + "</pre>");
```

Comment: Will give a try. Thanks for quick response

Answer (score 1):

In plain Javascript, you could use a temporary object for the reference to the target item and push all trips in another loop.

This solution assumes, that the `stop_id` matches in both arrays.

```js
function merge(array1, array2) {
    var o = {};
    array1.forEach(function (a) {
        o[a.stop_id] = a;
    });
    array2.forEach(function (a) {
        o[a.stop_id].trip = o[a.stop_id].trip || [];
        o[a.stop_id].trip.push(a);
    });
}

var array1 = [{ "stop_id": 70021, "stop_name": "CALTRAIN - 22ND ST STATION", "stop_lat": 37.757692, "stop_lon": -122.392318, "zone_id": 3329 }, { "stop_id": 70022, "stop_name": "CALTRAIN - 22ND ST STATION", "stop_lat": 37.757692, "stop_lon": -122.392318, "zone_id": 3329 }, { "stop_id": 70151, "stop_name": "CALTRAIN - ATHERTON STATION", "stop_lat": 37.464458, "stop_lon": -122.198152, "zone_id": 3331 }],
    array2 = [{ "trip_id": "RTD8997283", "arrival_time": "05:40:00", "departure_time": "05:40:00", "stop_id": 70021, "stop_sequence": 1 }, { "trip_id": "RTD8997283", "arrival_time": "05:52:00", "departure_time": "05:52:00", "stop_id": 70021, "stop_sequence": 2 }, { "trip_id": "RTD8449096", "arrival_time": "07:33:00", "departure_time": "07:33:00", "stop_id": 70022, "stop_sequence": 1 }];

merge(array1, array2);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Will give it a try. Great different approaches in the answers. Will try them all

Answer (score 1):

If browser support is not a problem, [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) might be the best solution for this case.

```
for (let item1 of arr1) {
  item1.trip = arr2.find(item2 => item2.stopid === item1.stopid);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little one-liner using `Array.prototype.map()`, assuming the first JSON sample is stored in `stops` and the second in `trips`. (Caveat: it requires an object extend function. I used jQuery's `$.extend()`, but any object extend method would work, e.g. Underscore/Lodash's `_.extend()` or Node.js's `util._extend`.)

```
var merged = stops.map(function(stop){ return $.extend({}, stop, {trip: trips.filter(function(trip) { return trip.stop_id === stop.stop_id; })}); })
```

If you like [ES6's arrow functions](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/), you can make this a bit prettier:

```
var merged = stops.map(stop=>$.extend({}, stop, {trip: trips.filter(trip => trip.stop_id === stop.stop_id)}))
```

Both of these will leave the original arrays unchanged, but if you simply want to merge the trips into the stops and you don't care about preserving the originals, you can remove the first argument to `$.extend()`; this is more efficient (especially with very large datasets), and you don't have to worry about keeping it in a variable:

```
stops.map(stop=>$.extend(stop, {trip: trips.filter(trip => trip.stop_id === stop.stop_id)}))
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` over `trains` and `filter` in the array of stations that match `stop_id`.

```
function getStations(stations, id) {
  return stations.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.stop_id === id;
  });
}

function mergeInfo(trains, stations) {
  return trains.map(function(obj) {
    var filtered = getStations(stations, obj.stop_id);
    if (filtered.length) obj.trip = filtered;
    return obj;
  });
}

var output = mergeInfo(trains, stations);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gxq1d6sa/1/)

Comment: Will give a try. Thanks for quick response